# Считать массив структур из файла

Tags: c++, fstream

мне нужно считать данные из файла в массив структур, вот мой код - узнаю длину файла(количество строк) и потом считываю, но получаю на выходе не то, что надо, в чем проблема?

```
int countLine = 0;
string line;

ifstream base(pchMessage);
while (getline(base, line))
    ++countLine;

Student *student = new Student[countLine];

int i = 0;
while (base)
{ 
    base >> student[i].id >> student[i].name >> student[i].surname >> student[i].rating;
    i++;
}

base.close();
```

в файле у меня:

```
111 aaa aaa 90
222 bbb bbb 72
```

Считывает с файла:

```
-842150451 -6.27744e+66
-842150451 -6.27744e+66
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вы же после этого

```
while (getline(base, line))
```

вышли на конец файла - что же вы там сможете прочесть? Вернитесь в начало файла для чтения заново.

Comment: спасибо, забыл про этот момент, вопрос решен)